# How to get special symbols echo through PHP to HTML document?

Tags: html, special-characters

I am trying to echo some special character like the "micro" symbol and the "squared" symbol however whenever I do this on the page it comes up with this symbol?

> �

These are ASCII chars I am using, perhaps I need UNICODE-8?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Which encoding are you using? ASCII doesn’t have these characters, and almost no website actually uses ASCII.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question specification (read: the stuff you didn't specify) your problem is in the encoding.

If your using PHP, then add `Header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");` to top of your code OR (even better:) to your core file (if your using some CMS type method.)

So browser would understand, what encoding your using add `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` to your html/template file.

Also make sure that your full mysql (if your using one) is in UTF-8 and make sure to add this to your mysql-macros class `mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");`.

Answer (score 1):

Only 7-bit ASCII is compatible with UTF-8. If you aren't specifically telling the browser that you are using a specific encoding, it is possible that it is assuming it is UTF-8.

Your best bet, for right now, with any non-standard characters is to use HTML entities such as `&sup2;` (²) and `&mu;` (μ), even if you do specify your text encoding properly to the browser.

Entities work, but long term, you should get your encoding sorted. UTF-8 is almost the de facto standard for encoding text on the web these days. Get your editor to output UTF-8, then make sure your webserver is serving your HTML with a `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8` header to make sure your browser interprets it as UTF-8.

Comment: “Your best bet …” – nonsense. Just use a proper encoding.

Comment: @Konrad: That'll almost certainly work, but does rely on the coder, browser, and server to all agree on the encoding, which isn't hard, but obviously isn't happening currently. Entities will always work, and take no extra effort in the short term to get working *right now*.

Comment: “entities always work” – except when you’re using XHTML and Firefox, where they don’t (well, numerical entities do work …). In fact, the latest consensus on named entities is “don’t use”.